# Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground available everywhere?

Tags: qt

I have a custom widget to emulate balloon tips. To be displayed properly, the widget depends on the QWidget attribute `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`. My application should work on all major platforms (Windows XP, Windows 7, Linux, Mac), so I worry a bit: Is this attribute available on all major platforms? If not, can I query if it is? `testAttribute()` doesn't do that. It only returns whether the attribute has been set, not whether setting it has an effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work with the only exception of Linux over X11 when this is configured not to support ARGB. Refer to the [QWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html) documentation:

> Creating Translucent Windows
>
> Since Qt 4.5, it has been possible to create windows with translucent
>   regions on window systems that support compositing.
>
> To enable this feature in a top-level widget, set its
>   Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground attribute with setAttribute() and ensure
>   that its background is painted with non-opaque colors in the regions
>   you want to be partially transparent.
>
> Platform notes:
>
> X11: This feature relies on the use of an X server that supports ARGB visuals and a compositing window manager.
>
> Windows: The widget needs to have the Qt::FramelessWindowHint window flag set for the translucency to work.

Consider reading also the paragraph titled "Transparency and Double Buffering", might be interesting.

Comment: How common or rare is it for a contemporary Linux to not support ARGB? Can I somehow query it?

Comment: I don't think you will have problems with that with recent hardware/distributions. Anyway you should get information by using xdpyinfo or looking at the configuration file xorg.conf. You might have some problems with embedded linux systems maybe. This gives something more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434511/what-pixel-format-does-x-server-use.

Answer (score 8):

For Linux you should check whether compositing is enabled:

```
bool QX11Info::isCompositingManagerRunning() [static]
```

e.g.

```
#ifdef Q_WS_X11
    if(QX11Info::isCompositingManagerRunning())
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
#endif
```

This question is old, but this might help someone.

Comment: And, for anyone who wanders in off Google, if you find yourself needing to support non-composited desktops for something like a rounded OSD or a speech balloon popup, the Qt [ShapedClock](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html) example demonstrates how to use `setMask` to produce a non-square window without compositing.

Comment: Note that sometimes to get `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` to work in linux without `setMask`, you also have to enable a few more attributes and a window flag. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30596357/999943