# mouse click from mpv in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a Qt application which uses mpv for playing different videos.
QWidget is used to show video content. I also have custom dock with controls for switching video channels, changing position, etc. 
I want to have dock appearing after a click on the screen and disappearing on timer event. It all works fine, except from the fact, that QWidget used for mpv is not receiving QMouseEvent. On the contrast same event works fine for main window. Basically dock appears only if you click on visible part of main window and not on mpv Qwidget.
I assume it is because mpv has internal support for keybindings. I've tried to disable them by setting "input-default-bindings" to "no", but it didn't help.

```
mpv_set_option_string(mpv, "input-default-bindings", "no");
```

Can anybody help with that?
Does anybody know how to configure keybindings for mpv (I can't find any example in documentation)?
Maybe there is a workaround for it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent widget in front of video area to receive and redirect `QMouseEvent` to your custom dock. Though this is not a beautiful solution... How to create such widget is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466030/make-qwidget-transparent).