# Qwidget transparent background without Mainwindow

Tags: qt, qwidget

I am trying to make QWidget transparent background, but all the codes I found here gave me black background altho it gives me a transparent background when I use it with MainWindow object but not Qwidget object!

some codes I used

```
  q->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
  q->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
  q->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
  q->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoBackground);
  q->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
```

and yes q is an QWidget object

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  You might also want to provide information about your platform, `Qt` version etc.

Comment: Mybe you find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466030/make-qwidget-transparent)

Comment: Do you want to show a transparent toplevel window? Or what exactly do you want to achieve?